# React filter items with dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and wanted to filter a list using a dropdown. I've almost got it but I can only click the drop down once and then the list will go empty. I'm pretty sure it's because I'm filtering the list and then it returns the list with the filtered items. But I'm not sure how to change that.

[demo](http://codepen.io/amwill/pen/pjxBmK?editors=011)

```
var filterData = [
  { name: 'Matthew', sex: 'male' },
  { name: 'Amanda', sex: 'female' }
 ];
var FilterForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: this.props.data,
      sex: ''
    }
  },
  handleChange: function(val) {
    // problem is here
    var filteredData = this.state.data.filter(function(item) {
      return item.sex === val;
    });
    this.setState({sex: val});
    this.setState({data: filteredData});
    console.log(filteredData);
  },
  render: function() {
    return ( 
      <div className="filter-form">
        <h1>Filter Form</h1>
        <FilterOptions data={this.state.data} changeOption={this.handleChange} /> 
        <FilterItems data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var FilterOptions = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: this.props.data,
      sex: ''
    }
  },
  handleChange: function(e) {
    var val = e.target.value;
    this.setState({bender: val});
    this.props.changeOption(val);
  },
  render: function() {
    return ( 
      <select id="sex" value={this.state.sex} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="male">male</option>
        <option value="female">female</option> 
      </select> 
    );
  }
});
var FilterItems = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: this.props.data
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="filter-item">
        {this.props.data.map(function(item) {
          return ( 
            <div>{item.name}</div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render( 
  <FilterForm data={filterData} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your `this.state.data` is updated when you selected the drop-down at the first time. You should use `this.props.data` as the searching source You can change like this :

```
   handleChange: function(val) {
    this.setState({sex: val});
    var filteredData;
    if(val == ""){
      filteredData = this.props.data;
    }else{
      filteredData = this.props.data.filter(function(item) {
      return item.sex === val;
    });
    }
```

Comment: also, do you know how i can get both results when the option is blank?

Comment: You can use `if` to decide the value of `filteredData`. I changed the answer. Could you mark my answer please ? Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

There another consideration for your code as well: the only component that really needs state is the filterform. The other components only need props.

This can really simplify and reduce your code.

- keep state in form only, and you only need to keep the selected filter in the state
- pass the filter options + selected filter to your options component
- pass the entire datalist + selected filter to your list component.

The following code also does exactly what you want (and reduces from 73 to 65 lines of code):

```
var data = [
      { name: 'Matthew', sex: 'male' },
      { name: 'Amanda', sex: 'female' }
     ];
    var FilterForm = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          sex: ''
        }
      },
      handleChange: function(val) {
        this.setState({sex: val});
        console.log(val);
      },
      render: function() {
        // create list of options from input data (based on sex)
        var optionsArray=this.props.data.map((item) => { return item.sex });
        optionsArray.unshift("");
        return ( 
          <div className="filter-form">
            <h1>Filter Form</h1>
            <FilterOptions options={optionsArray} selected={this.state.sex} changeOption={this.handleChange} /> 
            <FilterItems data={this.props.data} filter={this.state.sex} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
    var FilterOptions = React.createClass({
      handleChange: function(e) {
        var val = e.target.value;
        this.props.changeOption(val);
      },
      render: function() {
        var selectedOption = this.props.selected;
        return ( 
          <select id="sex" value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {this.props.options.map(option => {
              return <option key={option} value={option} selected={(option.value == selectedOption)}>{option}</option>;
            })}
          </select> 
        );
      }
    });
    var FilterItems = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        var filter = this.props.filter;
        var filteredData = this.props.data.filter((item) => {
          return (!filter || item.sex == filter)
        });

        return (
          <div className="filter-item">
            {filteredData.map(function(item) {
              return ( 
                <div>{item.name}</div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
    React.render( 
      <FilterForm data={data} />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

Comment: thank you! I'm not super familiar with `props` vs `state` so i just put state on everything

Comment: Is there a way to write everything in 1 class instead of 3 classes?

Comment: Yeah it could be in 1 class. FilterOptions and FilterItems are stateless. So only the form has state.